# Call function with unlimited params

Tags: php, arrays, function

I have **array**:

```
Array (
   foo => 1,
   bar => 2
   .......
)
```

And function with unlimit params, now I need to call function like this:

```
$x = myFunc(array('foo'=>1), array('bar'=>2),...);
```

Is it possible without eval?

Comment: why dont use it like: `$x = myFunc( $wholeArrayThere );`?

Comment: @N̨ul̕L͑P̯͍̭ȏͣ͛iƞer thanks, I searched but didn't find.

Comment: @Kasyx Because I can't change function.

Answer (score 1):

Use `func_get_args`.

Test Code:

```
function sum() {
    $sum = 0;
    foreach(func_get_args() as $arg)
        $sum += $arg;
    return $sum;
}

echo sum(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10);
```

Output:

```
55
```

Comment: He wants to call `sum`, not to implement `sum`.